# How can I encourage alien expansions?

Tags: factorio

I made a map intended purely as a sandbox for designing factory layouts, with peaceful mode, rich deposits, and water only in starting area. Apparently I also chose (or effectively chose) to have enemy bases be rare and distant.

This is a problem now, because I need large quantities of Alien Artifacts for my research and production.

In order of most to least preferred, I'd like to know one of these:

1. A **non-cheating** way to encourage the aliens to more frequently expand (create new base locations with spawners) **in peaceful mode**.
2. A way to do the same which does use console commands.
3. A command which will create a biter spawner.

Comment: It's been a while since I played, but from what I recall of the mechanics, killing them and letting pollution get near them causes more aliens to spawn.

Comment: @agent86 Aliens find places to attack by following pollution gradients, and pollution generation increases “evolution”, but I haven't heard of anything affecting expansions — hence this question.

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future, this question is now moot. [As of version 0.15](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-159), purple science no longer requires you to gather [Alien Artifacts](https://wiki.factorio.com/Alien_artifact). You can play the game without biters at all now if you want to. To disable biters completely, when generating a new map, go to *Resource Settings* and find *Enemy Bases* at the bottom of this list and set the *size* setting to *"None"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 0.12.20:

1. In peaceful mode enemies never expand.
2. `/c game.local_player.surface.set_multi_command{command={type=defines.command.build_base, destination={250, 100}, ignore_planner=1}, unit_count=10}` Size of the base is selected by `unit_count`. The biters that are used for building are not spawned by this command, there needs to be a nearby spawner that provides the settlers.
3. `/c game.local_player.surface.create_entity{name="biter-spawner", position={40, -40}}`

Outside peaceful mode the biters select a candidate position, and send a group there once in a while. The interval depends on evolution factor and is between 60 minutes and 5 minutes (controlled in `map-settings` prototype in game data).

Positions selected needs to be at between 3 and 7 chunks from existing base and at least 3 chunks from player buildings (controlled in `map-settings` again).
You can view chunks that are candidate for expansion wit debug view (F5 - F7 and F4) as green circles the map, the option name is called `show_enemy_expansion_candidate_chunks`.